# Plotting lists of doubles in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have one data type in my app which contains two lists:

```
class DeviceData {
    List<double> frequency;
    List<double> value;
    DeviceData({this.frequency, this.value});
}
```

I don't want to separate the data types in my app into individual nums due to it being reused everywhere from displaying raw data to writing/reading from the database. I need to plot the two lists in Flutter with frequency on the y axis and value on x.

All the libraries/packages I found on pub.dev use a data model containing pure int/double values to plot the data which they then convert into a list of that data model. I want to use lists containing all of x and all of y data, not one containing one x frequency corresponding to one y value. How does one do that? What if I want to use a map to plot the data?

An example:

```
SfCartesianChart(
    plotAreaBorderWidth: 0,
    primaryXAxis: NumericAxis(
        edgeLabelPlacement: EdgeLabelPlacement.shift,
        interval: 2,
        majorGridLines: MajorGridLines(width: 0)),
    primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(
        labelFormat: '{value}',
        axisLine: AxisLine(width: 0),
        majorTickLines: MajorTickLines(color: Colors.transparent)),
    series: <LineSeries<DeviceData, List<num>>>[
      LineSeries<DeviceData, List<num>>(
          animationDuration: 1500,
          dataSource: _result, //Contains List<DeviceData>
          xValueMapper: (DeviceData data, _) => data.frequency,
          yValueMapper: (DeviceData data, _) => data.value,
          width: 2,
          markerSettings: MarkerSettings(isVisible: true))
    ],
    tooltipBehavior: TooltipBehavior(enable: true),
);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily map your current `devideData` into a `List<SingleDeviceData>`:

```
dataSource: List.generate(
  deviceData.frequency.length,
  (index) => SingleDeviceData(
    frequency: deviceData.frequency[index],
    value: deviceData.value[index],
  ),
).toList(),
```

[image]

---

### Full source code for easy copy-paste:

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/charts.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyWidget(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SfCartesianChart(
      plotAreaBorderWidth: 0,
      primaryXAxis: NumericAxis(
          edgeLabelPlacement: EdgeLabelPlacement.shift,
          interval: 2,
          majorGridLines: MajorGridLines(width: 0)),
      primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(
          labelFormat: '{value}',
          axisLine: AxisLine(width: 0),
          majorTickLines: MajorTickLines(color: Colors.transparent)),
      series: dataList
          .map((deviceData) => LineSeries<SingleDeviceData, double>(
              animationDuration: 1500,
              dataSource: List.generate(
                deviceData.frequency.length,
                (index) => SingleDeviceData(
                  frequency: deviceData.frequency[index],
                  value: deviceData.value[index],
                ),
              ).toList(),
              xValueMapper: (SingleDeviceData data, _) => data.frequency,
              yValueMapper: (SingleDeviceData data, _) => data.value,
              width: 2,
              markerSettings: MarkerSettings(isVisible: true)))
          .toList(),
      tooltipBehavior: TooltipBehavior(enable: true),
    );
  }
}

class DeviceData {
  List<double> frequency;
  List<double> value;
  DeviceData({this.frequency, this.value});
}

class SingleDeviceData {
  final double frequency;
  final double value;

  SingleDeviceData({this.frequency, this.value});
}

final Random random = Random();

final List<DeviceData> dataList = List.generate(
  10,
  (_) => DeviceData(
    frequency: List.generate(100, (_) => random.nextDouble() * 100)..sort(),
    value: List.generate(100, (_) => random.nextDouble() * 10 - 3)
        .fold([0], (prev, curr) => prev..add(prev.last + curr)),
  ),
);
```